# Why does my texture file not show up?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm new to Blender. Very, *very* new.

I wanted to use it for some gfx things but I just can't figure out how to see the textures in the models that I download. I use free3d.com to download models that usually come with an OBJ file and an MTL file. Whenever I import the OBJ file into Blender and I switch the viewport shading into 'Texture' everything is still gray. I have tried it with several other models that I have downloaded and it keeps on giving the same problem. Maybe I'm just missing something because I only just started using Blender, but if anyone could inform me about this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Basically you have to manually create your own materials and texture them using the provided textures **inside** Blender and specifically for the render engine you plan on using

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! But where can I find the provided textures inside Blender?

Comment: Provided textures can't be found inside Blender, they should be saved on you hard drive along the downloaded models as regular image files, most commonly JPEG or PNG files. You then create materials in Blender and use those images as textures in them.

Comment: The thing is, I think the materials on the right (in this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/g5itty) are supposed to already have a texture but they're just not showing up? I have no idea how to find those textures or are they just simply non-existent?

Comment: Oh and! These are the only files that came with the download: https://prnt.sc/g5ivuf

Comment: Your downloaded models came with absolutely no textures at all, those in the list are materials, not textures. Role up your sleves, decide what render engine you want to use, activate it in the header, create some materials and download some textures from somewhere

Comment: I feel like such an idiot right now. Oh man..well, thank you anyway for helping me with this! At least now I know when I have textures or not. I appreciate it a lot!